Is subscribing to the NGRX action stream considered a code smell?
I ask myself if it's considered a code smell when directly subscribing to the NGRX action stream.
Consider the following use case:
Let's say I have a list of entities that is stored in the NGRX store. Updating a batch of entities via the UI dispatches actions for each updated entity that an effect listens to. The effect does invoke a REST call and dispatches a follow-up action depending on the REST call's success. In order to notify the UI (think of a progress bar or error toast), I may

subscribe to the action stream and listen for success / error actions dispatched by the effect
model the process state into the store and listen for these specific state changes
put custom events on a stream independent from the actions informing clients about the process

Subscribing to the action stream suits me best as I could keep the store free of process state that has a lifecycle as long as the process lasts, i.e. after the process finished the state is of no importance anymore. But is this considered a code smell, as I don't consume the action's payload that usually is send over the store's stream.
What makes me writing this question here on SO is that

I have no idea if the store is better kept for domain / entity data only, as modelling process states into it feels weird right now (maybe just because I lack the experience)
when you are having a multi-step process where just a few steps address the store, should the whole process be modelled into actions and effects
As dispatching actions and listings for state changes are somewhat loosly coupled, is introducing a unique id to actions a common approach to listen for a specific action to have been completed?

I know there won't be the one answer for these thoughts. It's more like questioning for some hints and perspectives on how to address the problem. That said, thank you for any ideas shared.

You've been through a lot of reflection but I can't help wondering, from what I've understood, the goal is to improve your app reactivity and user experience, if there is no change to the state of your ngrx store, is there really a need to go through this ? Couldn't you just push an error toast either in your effect or when subscribing to the http requests ?

Subscribing to the action stream (or just about anything else when using ngrx) is certainly a code smell. Create another effect which catches the error action and shows a toast, you can probably do something similar with the progress bar.

I can see that you have a few questions that must be addressed separately. Let's start with the main question:

Is subscribing to the NGRX action stream considered a code smell?

Yes. Action stream has its purpose and (in my opinion) it is well documented.

I have no idea if the store is better kept for domain / entity data only, as modelling process states into it feels weird right now (maybe just because I lack the experience)

No. Because otherwise the NGRX team wouldn't put there, for example, a router's state. Also the name "application state" implies that the store can contain not only pure data because just data entities certainly doesn't describe the whole application and how it behaves.
But this certainly doesn't mean that your feeling of weirdness is wrong. Maybe the app was really implemented in a weird way (I've seen this too).

when you are having a multi-step process where just a few steps address the store, should the whole process be modelled into actions and effects

Until certain degree. I would for sure review your approach if you find yourself hardcoding long chains of commands.

As dispatching actions and listings for state changes are somewhat loosly coupled, is introducing a unique id to actions a common approach to listen for a specific action to have been completed?

Frankly, I don't understand the question. Each action must have a unique ID by design, otherwise the whole reducer/effect logic won't work.
Not a question but still worth mentioning:

Subscribing to the action stream suits me best as I could keep the store free of process state that has a lifecycle as long as the process lasts, i.e. after the process finished the state is of no importance anymore.

NGRX implements a global application state. Not every piece of data belongs to the global application state. Maybe in your case something belongs to a local component's state but is stored in a wrong place, that's why you have this feeling of weirdness.
Here is a good video about NGRX: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JP4dEM4bjE8

If you read the NgRx documentation you'll find that subscribing to actions within components is against best practices/code smell.
This is also often used in discussions whether to use NgRx or other state management lib. It feels weird to do it the "right way", and it also means lines of code "for nothing". NgXs for example provides Action Handlers which you can subscribe to and handle success/error state with in-built functionality. Which is nice.
But since you are already using NgRx, you don't have that option. So I'll try to answer you questions based on my experience with NgRx. And then I'll give my opinions on how to solve your "issue".

Store is for keeping the state of the application. If ACTION_SUCCESS state modifies the UI or the app behavior in same way, than it should be in the store. Like in your case, batch is running and 2 out of 10 requests are completed => you can store it in state as 20% done of something.
By definition it should. Action can be dispatched without any payload and it does not need to be tied to a reducer. But it still can have an effect tied to it. Advantages are that you still see dispatched Actions in Dev Tools and it also allows you to write smaller effects, strictly dedicated to one purpose. Such effects are easier to understand and debug. With the usual NgRx disadvantage - too much boilerplate.
Although it's possible to do it I would avoid such solution. It would be quiet messy. I think there are better ways to do it. More below

So in your case I can think of two ways how to handle it:
Store Way

Create a property in the store for tracking the progress of the batch.
Each successful request in the batch will dispatch and Action which will trigger an effect. This action does not have a reducer.
In effect you'll calculate the progress (lets say using withLatestFrom) and dispatch and Action with result to save to the store.
Now create a Selector and progress bar can listen to its updates

Effect/Service Way

Create a service for handling the progress bar and inject it to the Effect
Each successful request in the batch will call the service method to update the progress
Inject the progress service into the component and subscribe to it for change updates

In both cases, your playing by the rules. And you still can use effects to handle other functionality, like for example routing or snack bars. It's still good idea to use separate Actions for that but as mentioned above, they don't need to be tied to Reducer. They'll just trigger an effect which will take care of the rest.
On real life example from my experience:
We had an Action dispatched after clicking on a save button in the form. It was tied to a reducer, which set 'isWorking' property to true -> disabling buttons. Its effect then handled the REST call and on success it dispatched an actions to display a snack, handle routing (delayed by snack time) and in the end it reverted the 'isWorking'.
This way component was only dispatching actions and had couple of simple selectors to react to smaller things. Rest of the logic was done in effects.
